# How to form a glob that works for a wild char or exact match?

Tags: python, glob

Iam using a statement such as :

```
input_stuff = '1,2,3'
glob(folder+'['+ input_stuff + ']'+'*')
```

to list files that begin with 1,2 or 3 while this lists files such as 1-my-file, 2-my-file, 3-my-file . 
This doesnt work if exact file names are given

```
input_stuff = '1-my-file, 2-my-file, 3-my-file'
glob(folder+'['+ input_stuff + ']'+'*')
```

The error is :`sre_constants.error: bad character range`

worse for :

```
input_stuff = '1-my-'
glob(folder+'['+ input_stuff + ']'+'*')
```

It prints everything in the folder such as 3-my-file etc.,

Is there a glob statement that will print files for both

```
input_stuff = '1,2,3'
```

or

```
input_stuff = '1-my-file, 2-my-file, 3-my-file'
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glob expression in brackets is a set of characters, not a list of strings.
You first expresion `input_stuff = '1,2,3'` is equivalent to `'123,'` and will also match a name starting with comma.
Your second expression contains `'-'`, which is used to denote character ranges like '`0-9A-F`', hence the error you get.

It is better to drop glob altogether, split `input_stuff` and use listdir.

```
import re, os

input_stuff = '1-my-file, 2-my-file, 3-my-file'
folder = '.'

prefixes = re.split(r'\s*,\s*', input_stuff) #split on commas with optional spaces
prefixes = tuple(prefixes) # startswith doesn't work with list
file_names = os.listdir(folder)
filtered_names = [os.path.join(folder, fname) for fname in file_names 
                  if file_name.startswith(prefixes)]
```

Comment: I had startswith in mind but, your explanation convinced me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
input_stuff = '1,2,3'
glob(folder+'['+input_stuff+']-my-file*')
```

EDIT: Since you said in your comment that you can't hardcode "-my-file", you can do something like:

```
input_stuff = '1,2,3'
name = "-my-file"
print glob.glob(folder+'['+input_stuff+']'+name+'*')
```

and then just change the "name" variable when you need to.

Comment: @Victor You didn't mention that in your question, but I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I cannot use like that because the user can input : input_stuff = '1,2,3' or input_stuff = '1-my-file, 1-my-stuff, 3-my-file'  or any such combination and single glob statement should work